# Calculating Windchill with different equations based on wind speed in R

Tags: r

R programming

I'm a new R programmer, trying to write a script that will calculate windchill with 3 different equations dependent on different wind speed paramaters. I was trying to use an apply function to do this.

The ingested data is a dataframe (csv file) where each row is a different weather observation, including station name, station id, time (year, month, day, hour), then the meteorological data, temp (DRY_BUILB_TEMP) and wind speed (WIND_SPEED). Only temp and windspeed are required to calculate the windchill.

The algorithm I used is as follows:

- Ingest the data
- Subset out the data where windspeed (v) has the following conditions: V >= 5, V > 1 & V < 5, V < 1
- Then I wrote a function for the first two subsets to calculate the windchill, two different equations. For the last condition windchill will equal temp.
- Then I tried to use the apply functions to calculate the windchill data with the proper function and subset.
- Then I try to cbind the original subset and windchill data back together.

The problem occurs with my apply function, I only want one response for each row in the data frame, the calculated windchill for that row of data. However I receive a calculated windchill for each column (all the same value) for each row. Which apply function should I use? Or should I subset the data out farther to only have the temp and wind speed data? Of course since I can't get a list of just windchills the end portion of the program does not work correctly either and the data cannot be cbinded to the subsets.

Here's the program I have so far:

```
data <- read.csv("HfxTestWind.csv")

data_1 <- subset(data, WIND_SPEED >= 5)
data_2 <- subset(data, WIND_SPEED > 1 & WIND_SPEED < 5)
data_3 <- subset(data, WIND_SPEED < 1)

windchill_1 <- function(temp1, wind1){
    temp1 <- data_1$DRY_BULB_TEMP
    wind1 <- data_1$WIND_SPEED
    result_1 <- 13.12 + 0.6215 * temp1 - 11.37 * (wind1 ^ (0.16)) + 0.3965* 
            temp1 * (wind1 ^ (0.16))
    return(result_1)
}

windchill_2 <- function(temp2, wind2){
    temp2 <- data_2$DRY_BULB_TEMP
    wind2 <- data_2$WIND_SPEED
    result_2 <- temp2 + ((-1.59 + 0.1345 * (temp2) / 5 * wind2))
    return(result_2)
}

WIND_CHILL_1 <- lapply(data_1, windchill_1)
data_comp_1 <- cbind(data_1, WIND_CHILL_1)

WIND_CHILL_2 <- lapply(data_2, windchill_2)
data_comp_2 <- cbind(data_2, WIND_CHILL_2)

WIND_CHILL_3 <- data_3$DRY_BULB_TEMP
data_comp_3 <- cbind(data_3, WIND_CHILL_3)
```

Comment: Well, there are a few issues here. Your `windchill_n` functions take in two arguments, but you are only supplying it it one. Change the inputs argument for your function to `data` then replace all references of `data_1, data_2` to `data`. Secondly, your `data` and all its derivatives reside belong to class `data.frame`. `lapply` operate column-wise for data.frames. You probably want row-wise operation with `apply(X = , MARGIN = 2, FUN = )`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop (`*apply` functions are loops) if you write a vectorized function. You should also study the topic of variable scoping in R.

```
#some data
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(DRY_BULB_TEMP = runif(100, -10, 30),
                 WIND_SPEED = runif(100, 0, 10))

windchill_1 <- function(temp, wind){ 
#note how I use the function's arguments inside the function
  result <- 13.12 + 0.6215 * temp - 11.37 * (wind ^ (0.16)) + 0.3965* 
    temp * (wind ^ (0.16))
  return(result)
}

windchill_2 <- function(temp, wind){
  result <- temp + ((-1.59 + 0.1345 * (temp) / 5 * wind))
  return(result)
}

windchill <- function (temp, V) {
  #you could nested ifelse here, but this is more efficient:
  wc <- temp
  wc[V >= 5] <- windchill_1(temp[V >= 5], V[V >= 5])
  wc[V > 1 & V < 5] <- windchill_2(temp[V > 1 & V < 5], V[V > 1 & V < 5])
  wc
}

DF <- within(DF, wchill <- windchill(DRY_BULB_TEMP, WIND_SPEED))

head(DF)
#  DRY_BULB_TEMP WIND_SPEED      wchill
#1     26.592242   6.262453 28.53904759
#2     27.483017   2.171577 27.49844851
#3      1.445581   2.165673 -0.06020394
#4     23.217905   3.889450 24.05710651
#5     15.669821   9.424557 15.47513150
#6     10.763838   9.626080  9.60641633
```

Answer (score 0):

R provides many ways of achieving the same result.  My take on this one might be something like

```
windchill <- function(temp, wind, lower=1, upper=5){
    ifelse(wind < lower, temp, 
       ifelse(wind < upper, temp + ((-1.59 + 0.1345 * (temp) / 5 * wind)), 
           13.12 + 0.6215*temp - 11.37*(wind^(0.16)) + 0.3965*temp*(wind^(0.16)) ) )
    }

data$WIND_CHILL <- windchill(data$DRY_BULB_TEMP, data$WIND_SPEED) 

head(data)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, in the end I opted for the shortest code version. However I am having one slight problem with the results now, for the initial case, (wind < lower, temp) the windchill should be the same as the temperature, this is not the case, it's always off in varying amounts (often higher) by up to 1 degree. Any solutions as to why?

Comment: Can you give an example of `wind` and `temp` which gives this claimed effect?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, I just realised I was looking at the incorrect tables and did not have my wind speeds tabled properly with the results. Thank you Henry, this was great, it works wonderfully,